# accessing the localstorage object value gives undefined when it was assigned to another variable in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, local-storage

Already my local Storage has some data 'Users' and in that object, I want to access an object inside it but I assigned it to another variable it gives me undefined

The error is 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined:

> 27:console.log(initialState.length);

```
const TaskListContextProvider = props => {
  const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) 
  var y;
  var em;
  for(var x=0;x<users.length;x++){
    var obj = users[x];
    if(obj.current == true){
        y=x;
        em = obj.Email;
        break;
    }else{
     console.log('error'); 
    }
  }
  console.log(users[y].Tasks.length);
  if(users[y].Tasks.length == 0){
    var initialState = []
  }else{
    console.log(users[y]);
    console.log(users[y].Tasks);
    var initialState = users[y].tasks
    console.log(initialState.length);
  }
```

[my react code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo8Ru.png)

my localStorage data:

```
[{Email: "rohit@devrushi.com", Password: "12345", current: true,…}]
0: {Email: "rohit@devrushi.com", Password: "12345", current: true,…}
Email: "rohit@devrushi.com"
Password: "12345"
current: true
Tasks: [{title: "qsw", desc: "wddc qwed", completed: false, id: "af5825b9-846a-466d-9ebe-1f09b100214d"}]
0: {title: "qsw", desc: "wddc qwed", completed: false, id: "af5825b9-846a-466d-9ebe-1f09b100214d"}
title: "qsw"
desc: "wddc qwed"
completed: false
id: "af5825b9-846a-466d-9ebe-1f09b100214d"
```

Comment: Why do you change the capitalization? Do you really have two properties that differ only in casing? That seems like it might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   console.log(users[y].Tasks);
   var initialState = users[y].tasks
```

Look at these two lines again. Do you spot the error?

...

It's `Tasks` vs `tasks`. Your `Tasks` property is an array, but your `tasks` property doesn't exist and hence is `undefined`.

You need to consistently write `Tasks` with upper-case `T` (or lower-case, but then *everywhere* lower-case!), because JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.